# shell scripting and running after switching to other user

Tags: shell-script, su

I have the following commands that I want to have them all in one shell file:

```
su – s3
lizinfo.sh –b
```

when the first linex executes, it prompts and the command prompt become like as below:

```
-bash-3.1$ (here I cant type second command >> lizinfo.sh –b)
```

I want to have my shell file run all of these command at once. But when I run my shell file it only runs the first line and for does not run the second line, and waits until I enter it manually.

Would you help me please ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `-c` option:

```
su - s3 -c "second command"
```